# LocalDate in my Rent array askes me to convert it to String

Tags: java

I need to add a date in my rent array, but Eclipse wants my LocalDate to be converted to a String and I don't want it to be String

```
public class Rent {

    private int id;
    private int days;

    public Rent(int id, LocalDate dateOfRent, int d1, LocalDate returnDate) {
        this.id = id;
        dateOfRent = LocalDate.now();
        days = d1;
        returnDate = LocalDate.now();
    }
}
```

On my Rent array the error  shows up on the dates given, it asks me to convert it into String and more error coming up in my application

```
Rent[] rentArray = { 
    new Rent(61, "2019-05-16", 5, "2019-05-21"),
    new Rent(55, "2019-02-16", 10,"2019-02-26"),
    new Rent(51, "2019-01-09", 7, "2019-01-19"),
};
```

Comment: `"2019-05-16"` is not a `LocalDate`. `LocalDate.parse("2019-05-16")` is, though.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I implement that inside my Rent [] rentArray?

Comment: Your third example doesn't make sense to me. How can I rent a bike for 7 days, but return it 10 days later? Either this must be a special discount, or you should remove one of the constructor parameters: either the `d1` or the `returnDate` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56178869/localdate-in-my-rent-array-askes-me-to-convert-it-to-string#comment98983972_56178869):

> Thanks, but how can I implement that inside my Rent [] rentArray?

You create a convenience constructor, i.e. an overload / alternative constructor:

```
public Rent(int id, String dateOfRent, int d1, String returnDate) {
    this(id, LocalDate.parse(dateOfRent), d1, LocalDate.parse(returnDate));
}
```

Now your code will work as written.

Answer (score 0):

As @shmosel has said, you can do something like this:

```
Rent[] rentArray = { 
        new Rent(61, LocalDate.parse("2019-05-16"), 5, LocalDate.parse("2019-05-21")),
        new Rent(55, LocalDate.parse("2019-02-16"), 10, LocalDate.parse("2019-02-26")),
        new Rent(51, LocalDate.parse("2019-01-09"), 7, LocalDate.parse("2019-01-19")) 
        };
```

or modify your constructor, to take dates as String and then parse it using
`LocalDate.parse` inside the constructor